# Cannot make a call using Agora API with restricted network acces (android platforms)

Tags: java, android, agora.io

We are using Agora API client for video call purpose, but recently we had an issue in some environnements with  restricted network access, they cannot make a call ! what we should do to allow agora flow ?

Answer (score 0):

Agora provides dual-stream mode to ensure video stream connection under challenging network condition. What it does is it allows the streamers send a high quality video stream and a low quality video stream at the same time. You (developer) can choose to receive the low quality stream when the network is bad to improve communication continuity.

Here is the doc for dual-stream mode: https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/fallback_android?platform=Android

Comment: Hi Shaocheng, Thanks for you answer !
What i'm asking, it's that in some environnement, the network is restricted with firewalls or other tricks, how we deal with it ?